# How to change value of Java swing JTextArea dynamically

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

> ```
> private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(2000);
>             jTextArea1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
>         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
>             Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
>         }
>     }
> }
> private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
> ```

After every 2 seconds I need to change the value of jTextArea1. But it shows only the final value which is '9'.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: From where is this code executed (which threads executes it, where is this code placed)?

Comment: So, to answer the question of @Pshemo - the latest (uncompilable) code snippet indicates 'the EDT'.  My close vote was spot on..  ;)

Comment: @Andrew - Couldn't find 'Event Dispatch Thread'. I'm using netbeans 8 for create the application.

Comment: *"Couldn't find 'Event Dispatch Thread'."*  ..did you check under the couch?  I don't understand what you are trying to say there.  *"I'm using netbeans 8 for create the application."*  Are you sure it is not the other way around?  Seems like the IDE is using you at the moment.

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    jTextArea1.setText(String.valueOf(i));
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
  }
    }
}).start();  ///This works for me